# Sitecore WFFM - Creating a new Save Action Editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

I've created a custom save action for WebForms for Marketers and have already given it a few settings. The save action is set to use control:Forms.MappingFields as the control, with a query string of "Fields=EmailAddress|EmailAddress,Name|Name"

This works great for specifying which of the form fields are the Email Address and Name, which are later used in a Campaign Monitor newsletter subscription. **What I want to do now, is provide the content creators with the ability to specify the Campaign Monitor List ID (which is a string) and allow that string to be different for each form that uses this save action.**

The only way that I know how to do this, is to modify the save action's Editor.

Using [this article](http://adeneys.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/custom-wfm-action-settings-ui/), I started working on a new Editor UI. However, I'm having two problems.

1. I created a new .cs file and used the code provided in the article, but I'm getting the error: *The type 'System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderCollection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. (Line 48.)* I tried adding a using for System.Configuration but doing so doesn't solve the problem.
2. The bigger problem, is that I don't know what to do with the XML that the article provides. I found [an article on SDN about creating Sheer UIs](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/XML%20Sheer%20UI/My%20first%20XML%20application.aspx), however the article is outdated. It directs me to [an article about XML Application Creation](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Articles/Customizing%20Sitecore%20Client/Creating%20XML%20Application.aspx), but that is also outdated as I am using Sitecore 6.5. The screenshots are obviously not accurate for Sitecore 6.5, and the *New XML Layout* option in the context menu is not available.

So what I'm hoping to find is an example on creating a new Editor for a WebForms for Marketers save action, that is updated for WFFM 2.3 and Sitecore 6.5, which doesn't already assume that I know how to create XML Application Layouts. Either that, or an easier way to let content creators specify a string which is different per-form.

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at the files in /sitecore/shell/applications/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Dialogs/ and use reflector to see how the save actions are implemented. That might help you out.